# Vector drawable stop app from building

Tags: android, svg, vector

I am using vector drawable in my app. I have changed color for vector from path of the xml. but after this when I give the app run it shows this error [image: gradle failed to build] please help me, I am new to vector drawables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ran into this same problem once . In my case I didn't have to change the path color to `android:fillColor="#fff"`

here is my xml of a svg

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="512dp"
    android:height="512dp"
    android:viewportWidth="42.0"
    android:viewportHeight="42.0">
<path
    android:pathData="M0,20h42v2h-42z"
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M21,13c2.76,0 5,-2.24 5,-5s-2.24,-5 -5,-5s-5,2.24 -5,5S18.24,13 21,13zM21,5c1.65,0 3,1.35 3,3s-1.35,3 -3,3s-3,-1.35 -3,-3S19.35,5 21,5z"
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M21,29c-2.76,0 -5,2.24 -5,5s2.24,5 5,5s5,-2.24 5,-5S23.76,29 21,29zM21,37c-1.65,0 -3,-1.35 -3,-3s1.35,-3 3,-3s3,1.35 3,3S22.65,37 21,37z"
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Look I didn't change to color reference . although my minSDK was 14 . what I did wrong was I didn't add this line to app level gradle file

```
android{
     ....
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

I am not sure you did the same mistake . let me know if it is the same case with you

Answer (score 1):

You're using the version of vector compatibility that parses your `<vector>` and generates `.png` files of different resolutions. As the error message says, this process doesn't support references to other resources (in your case `@android:color/white`).

Change this:

```
android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
```

to:

```
android:fillColor="#fff"
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the limitation of the tool. 
`android:fillColor="@android:color/white"` will work for API 21, if you run your apps on the device, or set the Android Studio's preview window's API level >=21.

But it won't work for our backward support (XML -> PNG) path in order to support API < 21.

So In Your case

Change

```
android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
```

To

```
android:fillColor="#ffffff"
```

For more reffer this link
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37061710